# How to save ngChange in localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, controller

I need a ngchange in my dropdown menu to save to localstorage so when somebody closes the app the change is still saved. Right now everything is working but when the app is reloaded the user has to make the selection again. How do I get it to work?

Here is the HTML:

```
<select  ng-model="item" ng-options="category.title for category in categories | filter: 234 | filter: {title: '!Federal'} "
 ng-change="changedValue(item)"  style="text-align: left;">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a State</option>
</select>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$scope.changedValue = function(item) {
 $scope.categories.push(item.id);


console.log(item.id);
$localStorage.id = item.id;
console.log($scope.categories);
$scope.categories = $localStorage.categories;


$http.get('http://mywebsite.com/api/get_category_posts/?id=' + item.id).then(
  function(data){


    $scope.category_posts = data.data.posts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set an item in LocalStorage :**

```
localStorage.setItem('selectedOption', JSON.stringify(item));
```

**Get an item from LocalStorage :**

```
var lastSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedOption'));
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.categories = [
   {
    "title":"uttarakhand",
    "name":"uttarakhand"
   },
   {
    "title":"himachal",
    "name":"himachal"   
   },
   {
    "title":"telangana",
    "name":"telangana"   
   }
   ];
   
   var lastSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedOption'));
   
   if(lastSelected) {
     $scope.item = lastSelected; 
   }
   
   $scope.changedValue = function(item) {
     localStorage.setItem('selectedOption', JSON.stringify(item));
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select  ng-model="item" ng-options="category.title for category in categories"
 ng-change="changedValue(item)"  style="text-align: left;">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a State</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store data in local storage as

```
localStorage.setItem('ID', item.id);
```

So you can get the data after reload as

```
$scope.categories = localStorage.getItem('ID');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store anything in localStorage then you can do it as below. It should have a key and value.

```
localStorage.setItem('category', 'PRODUCTS');
```

If you want to get the same, use the key. In your case, where it is needed, use the below line to fetch the data back

```
localStorage.getItem('category');
```